# EXCEL/VBA - if cell in sheet1 equals cell sheet2 copy row to sheet3

Tags: excel, compare, paste, vba

I have text values in column A sheet1 (250 rows) and values in column A sheet2 (10000 rows) and I need to compare these values - sheet1 to sheet2. If value from sheet1 matchs to sheet2, copy row from sheet2 to sheet3.

Do you have any idea how to do it? I spent almost whole day trying to figure out how to code it. Thank you for help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  SO is not a "Code for me Site" nor is it a "Teach me to Code Site".  Please post your attempt at doing this so we can help with the specific problem with the existing code.

Comment: Please do Google Search. If i can find a suitable reference, You can also find with some efforts. This should get you going.<http://ccm.net/forum/affich-756470-comparing-two-excel-sheets-and-copying-like-data-to-third-sheet>

Answer (score 0):

Next time try Googling first: [compare values in two sheets excel](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&btnI=I%27m%20Feeling%20Lucky&pws=0&q=compare%20values%20in%20two%20sheets%20excel&safe=active&gws_rd=ssl)

First result. Scroll down. Section titled "How to compare two Excel sheets for differences in values". That's the first part, checking if the values are the same.

Second part: Again, first result when googling: "send value from one sheet to another excel"
http://ccm.net/faq/9795-transfer-data-between-excel-spreadsheets

Third part: Combine these two with a conditional.
Google: "IF statement excel".

After you've tried it on your own, if you have any issues, edit your question with your attempt and result. Do this before asking next time.

I'll be more than happy to help you fix your errors (if any) when we've seen what you've tried!

Good luck.